# I can see file size but not able to open the file

Tags: file, unix

I can file size in MBs but when I am trying to open the file I can't ... saying can't find file.

```
while read line; do echo $line # or whaterver you want to do with the $line variable 
    cat $line | grep "PROCEDURE" > result3.txt
    chmod 777 result3.txt
done < xreflist.txt;
```

Comment: Doing `grep "PROCEDURE" xreflist.txt > result3.txt` would be enough to get the result, no loop needed. `chmod` outside the loop, doing it only once, would be better.

Comment: xreflist.txt file contains name of files that I need to read and output lines having UPDATE in those files.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Did not think enough about the code. Because it is unclear, which file can't be found, you may do a `ls -l xreflist` before, a `ls -l $line` in the loop and a `ls -l resutl3.txt`after the loop. Or add proper error handling `if [ ! -r $line ]; then echo "$line not readable"; continue; fi`

Answer (score 1):

To be able to find the file size, you need permission to read the directory.

To be able to open the file, you need permission to read the file.

It is perfectly possible to be able to do the one without the other.

```
$ mkdir junk
$ cd junk
$ echo "Hello World" > no-permission
$ chmod 0 no-permission
$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   3 jonathanleffler  staff   96 Dec 29 11:34 .
drwxr-xr-x  18 jonathanleffler  staff  576 Dec 29 11:34 ..
----------   1 jonathanleffler  staff   12 Dec 29 11:34 no-permission
$ cat ./no-permission
cat: ./no-permission: Permission denied
$ rm -f ./no-permission
$ cd ..
$ rmdir junk
$
```

Comment: 777 permission is available at both directory and file level... but still same problem 
-rwxrwxrwx   1 dslayad    ds2           1402 Dec 29 11:27 result3.txt

Comment: You need to edit your question to show what's happening more clearly.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]). You should show a minimal (2 or 3 line) `xreflist.txt`, and show the permissions on the files and directory — basically like I did in my answer. The `chmod 777` is bad news.  Your file is unlikely to contain executable code; don't make it executable.  You are permitting any user on the machine to write to the file, so you don't care about the content. Don't use 777 permission; it is silly — using 644 would probably be sensible, unless you don't want the content that visible.